# When does NHibernate execute my query?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am trying to write a generic repository for my NHibernate data access. The `Get<T>()` method should be able to take an optional predicate, that should be included in the query - that is, NHibernate should generate the WHERE clause in the SQL.

```
    public virtual IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> predicate = null)
    {
        // Open NHibernate Session
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            return (predicate != null
                       ? session.Query<T>().Where(predicate)
                       : session.Query<T>()).ToList();

    }
```

When I pass in a predicate, and observe the SQL statement NH generates, I see no where clause.

When does NHibernate execute the query? Right when calling `.Query<T>()`? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query should be executed by the call `ToList()`.

The case why the WHERE clause is not included in your sql statement is that you need to pass an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` to your method.

```
public virtual IList<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        // Open NHibernate Session
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            return (predicate != null
                       ? session.Query<T>().Where(predicate)
                       : session.Query<T>()).ToList();

    }
```

The extension method `Where(Func<T,bool>>)` is defined on [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx), so that the the query loads all data and then applies the WHERE-filter in memory.

The extension method `Where(Expression<Func<T,bool>>)` is defined on [Queryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx), so that the query provider (NHibernate) can build a sql statement including your WHERE condition that gets executed on the data source.

Comment: Thanks, absolutely perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Since @Jehof gave you correct explanation I just want to add separate note - you should not return `IList<T>` from you repository method as then any other linq operation will be executed in memory and not in the database. Assume following calls

```
var data = repository.Get<Company>(c=>c.Name.StartsWith("MyCompany"));
... some other operations / method calls etc.
var companySubset = data.Where(...);
```

so now if you have `IList<T> Get<T>()` you decrease performance but with `IQueryable<T> Get<T>` you would still have the second Where() appended to the database query.

Of course not all linq operations are supported by `IQueryable` like (join , last ) and this is the only place to call `ToList()` extension to evaluate expression.

Comment: That is the point, but thanks for your note :) - I dont want my business logic to trigger DB calls when I dont explicitly ask for it.